# SwiftUI layout - How to align center correctly?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm wondering how could I align correctly the second `Text` at the middle because in this example it depends of the `Text`s to the left and right.

I'd love to have the `Text("Not really in the middle")` perfectly aligned to the center.

```
HStack {
    Text("Left")
    Spacer()
    Text("Not really in the middle")
    Spacer()
    Text("Right but long")
}
```

Maybe, there's a modifier for it that I don't know about? Because using a `Grid` for this part seems to be exaggerated? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know of is to use a ZStack:

```swift
ZStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Left")

        Spacer()

        Text("Right but long")
    }

    Text("In the middle")
}
```

However, this has the problem that it doesn't prevent the texts from overlapping. To solve that is much more complicated; here's one potential solution using `GeometryReader`:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State var totalWidth: CGFloat = 0
    @State var leftWidth: CGFloat = 0
    @State var rightWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    var middleWidth: CGFloat { totalWidth - 2 * max(leftWidth, rightWidth) }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader(content: updateTotalWidth)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Left")
                    .overlay(GeometryReader(content: updateLeftWidth))
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: (totalWidth - middleWidth) / 2 - leftWidth)
                
                Text("In the middle but longer")
                    .frame(width: middleWidth)
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: (totalWidth - middleWidth) / 2 - rightWidth)
                
                Text("Right but long")
                    .overlay(GeometryReader(content: updateRightWidth))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateTotalWidth(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        self.totalWidth = proxy.size.width
        return EmptyView()
    }
    
    private func updateLeftWidth(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        self.leftWidth = proxy.size.width
        return EmptyView()
    }
    
    private func updateRightWidth(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        self.rightWidth = proxy.size.width
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one is what I needed as I have a lot of space to avoid the overlapping problem. But the second one could be useful for others as well. Thanks again!